# Analyze sound live with aubio?

Tags: python, audio, aubio

Is there any way for the aubio library to analyze sound **live**? I can get it to analyze a saved audio file just fine, but it does not seem to want to work with microphone inputs. Documentation for the Python library seems just about non-existent. All I found were [these](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/tree/master/python/demos) examples, none of which seem to deal with analysis of live input. Has anyone managed to work with live input before, and how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/aubio/aubio/issues/78 and https://github.com/aubio/aubio/issues/6

Demo here: https://github.com/aubio/aubio/blob/master/python/demos/demo_pyaudio.py

Please open a new issue whenever you have a question, or use https://aubio.org/contact